# Trying to use a tool but I get the following error KeyError: 'str'

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a Medical Concept Annotation tool. The documentation can be found here: https://github.com/CogStack/MedCAT

The `med_ann_norm_dict.dat` file was downloaded from github from this section:

```
Building a new Concept Database (.csv) or using an existing one
First download the vocabulary from Vocabulary Download
```

The code that I have is:

```
from medcat.cat import CAT
from medcat.utils.vocab import Vocab
from medcat.prepare_cdb import PrepareCDB
from medcat.cdb import CDB

vocab = Vocab()
#Load the vocab model
vocab.load_dict('C:/Users/as/Desktop/Data/med_ann_norm_dict.dat')

#build a special CDB from a .csv file
preparator = PrepareCDB(vocab=vocab)
csv_paths = ['C:/Users/as/Desktop/Data/ICD10Codes.csv']
cdb = preparator.prepare_csvs(csv_paths)

#Annotate the text
doc = text
cat = CAT(cdb=cdb, vocab=vocab)
#Entities are in 
doc_spacy._.ents
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-195-32d167ab52db>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/as/Desktop/Data/Preprocessing.py', wdir='C:/Users/as/Desktop/Data')

  File "C:\Users\as\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\as\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/as/Desktop/Data/Preprocessing.py", line 198, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/as/Desktop/Data/Preprocessing.py", line 193, in main
    preproc.parse()

  File "C:/Users/as/Desktop/Data/Preprocessing.py", line 135, in parse
    self.medcat(text)

  File "C:/Users/as/Desktop/Data/Preprocessing.py", line 181, in medcat
    cdb = preparator.prepare_csvs(csv_paths)

  File "C:\Users\as\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\medcat\prepare_cdb.py", line 55, in prepare_csvs
    names = str(df.iloc[ind]['str']).split(self.NAME_SEPARATOR)

  File "C:\Users\as\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 868, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

  File "C:\Users\as\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4389, in get_value
    raise e1

  File "C:\Users\as\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4375, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 81, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 89, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'str'
```

I don't understand exactly why I get this error.

The CSV file that I am trying to load in this line `cdb = preparator.prepare_csvs(csv_paths)`, has two columns and looks like this:

```
A00     Cholera
A000    Malignant
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the file for the vocab dict.

Comment: It's a .dat file and I downloaded it from here: https://github.com/CogStack/MedCAT

Comment: Please either provide a direct link or the contents. I can't find that file. I can find that exact name in config files but as per `.gitignore` they aren't where that config shows...

Comment: Yeah, just as I thought, this file is not in the repo - `RUN wget "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/zkcl/med_ann_norm_dict.dat" -P /cat/models/` Anyway, probably bad clue, I thought vocab dict had something to do with the keys.

Comment: I just edited the question. It's a section that says `Building a new Concept Database (.csv) or using an existing one
First download the vocabulary from Vocabulary Download` and I saved it from there. Just had to click on download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MedCat needs you to label your columns with a heading. You are required to have at least `cui` and `str`. See the example table at https://github.com/CogStack/MedCAT/blob/d1be623a380881a5c8e4e17622a884b9fb3cfa85/examples/simple_cdb.csv